# C# regular expression for comma separated letter subset

Tags: c#, regex

How can I allow **up to** 2 commas in this regular expression? It needs to be used with [RegularExpressionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=netframework-4.6.1) on a class property.

`A|B|C|D|F|I|a|b|c|d|f|i`

For instance these should be valid inputs:

- A
- A,b
- C,D,A

Invalid inputs:

- D,C,B,A (more than 2 commas)
- D,,C (two consecutive commas)
- H,A (outside letter range)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?i)^[A-DFI](?:,[A-DFI]){0,2}$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fi%29%5E%5BA-DFI%5D%28%3F%3A%2C%5BA-DFI%5D%29%7B0%2C2%7D%5Cr%3F%24&i=A%0D%0AA%2Cb%0D%0AC%2CD%2CA%0D%0A%0D%0AD%2CC%2CB%2CA%0D%0AD%2C%2CC%0D%0AH%2CA&o=m)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-DFI]` - `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `F`, `I` (case insensitively)
- `(?:,[A-DFI]){0,2}` - 0, 1 or 2 occurrences of

  - `,` - comma
  - `[A-DFI]` - `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `F`, `I` (case insensitively)
- `$` - end of string.

In C#:

```
var IsValid = Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^[A-DFI](?:,[A-DFI]){0,2}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned, I need to use this regex with RegularExpressionAttribute on a class property. The input `C,c` is being returned invalid by `@"^[A-DFI](?:,[A-DFI]){0,2}$"`

Comment: @joym8 Yes, then you have to use `"^[A-DFIa-dfi](?:,[A-DFIa-dfi]){0,2}$"`. Or even `"[A-DFIa-dfi](?:,[A-DFIa-dfi]){0,2}"` since the whole string must match the pattern anyway (it is just how `RegularExpressionAttribute` validates the string).